# redirect after login on login dialog

Tags: jsf, authentication, redirect

tl;dr: My question can actually be resumed to how the heck do I refresh the page via a String (when get params are unknow)?

I've two scenarios to log in users:

- unauthenticated user access a page that is protected he is redirected towards a login page. When logged in he is redirected towards the page he primarily tried to access.
- unauthenticated user clicks on a button on my page that if the user is unauthenticated will display a log in modal dialog

for example like this :

```
<!-- user connected -->
<p:commandButton action="#{pollVoteBean.vote}" value="#{strings.Vote}" rendered="#{userNav.isUserConnected}"/>
<!-- user disconnected -->
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{!userNav.isUserConnected}">
    <p:commandButton type="button" value="#{strings.Vote}" onclick="PF('regSign').show()"/>
<!-- if the user clicks here a log in dialog appears and he can log in. -->
</h:panelGroup>
```

When unauthenticated user clicks this appears :

[image]

This is what I use on the sign in page to redirect user is :

```
lastUrl = getCorrectUrl(((String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext().getRequestMap()
        .get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)));

if (null != lastUrl && !"/signin".equals(lastUrl))
    return lastUrl + "?faces-redirect=true";
else
    return "/news?faces-redirect=true";
```

However for the dialog I'd like to refresh the page. How can I change the code above so it takes care of both scenarios?

I'm almost there but I can't get the correct url with parameters (which are unknowns of course):

```
lastUrl = getCorrectUrl(((String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getRequestMap()
            .get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI)));
currentUrl = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
        .getViewId();
if ("/signin".equals(currentUrl)) {
    if (null != lastUrl && !"/signin".equals(lastUrl))
        return lastUrl + "?faces-redirect=true";
    else
        return "/news?faces-redirect=true";
} else {
    return currentUrl + "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

( The codes above are assuming the user correctly authenticated).
Also my dialog is `dynamic="true"`.

Comment: @Tiny I ended up just going the easy route and split my function in two. Could you tell me why you said it's not a plausible requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up splitting the method in two since I found no easy way to do this.

```
public String signInUser() {
    if (trySignIn()) {
        if (null != lastUrl && !"/signin".equals(lastUrl))
            return lastUrl + "?faces-redirect=true";
        else
            return "/news?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        return "signin.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}

public void signInFromDlg() {
    trySignIn();
}
```

Then a javascript refresh oncomplete.